# Unresolved reference Math in InteliJ IDEA Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, math, compiler-errors

I have this code, it works, but compiler InteliJ IDEA doesn't see Math package and it's methods.
It defines Math like unresolved reference and propose to create class "Math". How to solve this problem?

```
import kotlin.math.*

fun main() {

 println(five("rain"))
 }
fun five(a: String) = a.substring(0, Math.min(5, a.length))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `Math.` part. So like

```
fun five(a: String) = a.substring(0, min(5, a.length))
```

The import makes the `min` function available just like that. Don't need to write `Math.` in front of it